# trustExitCode = false not working with Araxis merge for mac and Git

Tags: git, mergetool, araxis

I have this in my config file:

```
[merge]
        tool = araxismergetool
        trustExitCode = false

[mergetool]
        keepBackup = false
        trustExitCode = false
        prompt = true
[mergetool "araxismergetool"]
        trustExitCode = false
        cmd = araxisgitmerge $PWD/$REMOTE $PWD/$BASE $PWD/$LOCAL $PWD/$MERGED
```

I call up the mergetool on a conflicted file edit it and save the file.  I would expect git to prompt me if the merge worked or not to which I would need to reply (y)es/(n)o.

It's not doing that… it's just simply staging the file automatically with my edits.

This used to work for me.

My git version 1.7.12.4 (Apple Git-37)
My araxis version is 2013.4283

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

I've also tried just setting the tool to "araxis".

I've also tried throwing an error in the "araxisgitmerge" oascript with no luck.

To me it seems like trustExitCode = false is simply not working.

Comment: I am also seeing the same thing with p4merge.  It always asked me before, but not anymore.